# ubuntu 13.10 ftp Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server

Tags: apache2, 13.10, lamp, ftp

i have done a little google searching on this one, but im not really finding a solution that is helping.

I have Ubuntu 13.10 LAMP (64bit) installed on VM-VirtualBox running on Windows 7x64. After trying to set up the LAMP using tasksel (a complete failure), i ended up installing all components through the GUI using synaptic without any problems. I have then installed a wordpress website on the LAMP and am able to access it both locally on the virtual machine and via my static ip address over the web from my iphone.

I am now having problems with permissions i believe as i am unable to add/remove plugins and media to the site.It brings up an ftp connection window asking for details and when i insert the appropriate information i get errors such as

**from wordpress**

ERROR: There was an error connecting to the server, Please verify the settings are correct.

**If i then try to connect remotely using file zilla**

Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server

I have another virtual machine running ubuntu 12.04 LAMP with wordpress installed. I dont have any problems ftp'ing to that system from within wordpress or using filezilla. I cant for the life of me figure out what i have done differently???

Is the ubuntu 13.10 apache2 server not listening???

what are the most common causes of an "ECONNREFUSED" response from the server?

Is there an web server dependency that should have been installed that synaptic missed???

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Strange behaviour, but proftpd suddenly stopped. This helps me:

```
sudo service proftpd start
```

If you want to add this to autorun execute the following command:

```
sudo update-rc.d proftpd defaults
```